# How to implement a "quit to upgrade and restart" installer?

Tags: qt, installation, cross-platform

Many applications have this functionality now, but a good example is the Spotify client.

The app discovers there is a new version available, downloads it in the background then prompts the user to restart to get the new version. When the user quits the new version is installed (or the installed version is patched) then the application is restarted, all without further user interaction.  In fact, the user really doesn't even have to do anything the app would automatically update on every exit if the user was never notified.

We have a cross-platform Qt 5.3 application and our lean startup business model requires us to push application updates very often so I'd really like to find a method that works cross platform with as little platform specific code as possible.

There are multiple parts to this question.

1. Noticing the update, and downloading the installer. (Obvious, and not a problem)
2. Running the installer application. Not an issue except how does one gain privilege? Spotify never asks for privilage to install again after the first install.
3. Avoiding "This application has been downloaded from the Internet" approval dialogue on every update.
4. Restarting the application after upgrading, but only when the user responded to the quit and upgrade prompt.

Specifically are there any tools, installers or code examples that do this?

Comment: Have a "controller" background process, which internally launches your app as a new `QProcess`, when update is available, the controller process can signal the app to terminate, apply the update and relaunch the application.

Comment: @ddriver. The "controller" would nececarally be overwritten during the update if it is part of the installed package set. I can see how it could launch the installer but the controller would then need to quit, and so would be unable to follow through on the relaunch. The installer could presumably look for some saved state to know when to relaunch the app directly from the installer, but there are privilage issues.

Comment: Make a distinction between installer and updater, the installer installs both controller and application, updater doesn't touch the controller, only the application part. Make the controller encapsulated and future proof, do not rely on it for more than starting and updating, so that the controller itself never needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow how Google Chrome and Opera (latest one, not version <= 12) do it, rougly as below:

1. When installing the application, create a scheduled task that runs an updater as administrator (or a user with permission to write files to your application directory) periodically. For example in Windows, you can find `GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore` and `GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA` entries in Task Scheduler.
2. Your application structure looks something like the following (Google Chrome has similar structure in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application`):

   > C:\Program Files\AwesomeApp\launcher.exe
   >
   > C:\Program Files\AwesomeApp\1.0\AwesomeApp.exe  ; version 1.0 of application
   >
   > C:\Program Files\AwesomeApp\1.2\AwesomeApp.exe  ; version 1.2 of application
3. The application shortcut created by installer will run launcher.exe. This launcher.exe will run the latest version of AwesomeApp.exe available in the directory. For example in the above structure, launcher.exe will run `AwesomeApp\1.2\AwesomeApp.exe`.
4. When the updater finds an update, it will download it and add the new version to the directory in the background. After that it will tell the running application (if it is running) to notify the user that an update is ready and can be used by restarting the application. And of course your older application needs to close itself and restart by running launcher.exe too. This updater may delete old application versions and keep only the latest two versions.